# Express Set up conditional loading of stylesheets based on current page being loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, conditional-statements

**EDIT: I modified my app.js part so that I can pass in files and just do something like what I did with the title, but it doesn't work for some reason.**

I currently have my header.ejs page loading the index stylesheet on every page.

```
<head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='public/css/style.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='public/css/index.css'>
</head>
```

What I am hoping to do is set up a conditional loading system for all of my stylesheets. using parameters passed when I call `res.render()` on that page. possible to set up something like what I have tried to below?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= cssFile1 %>">
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res, index-styles, index-script) {
    var pageTitle = getPageTitle('Home');
    res.render('index', {
        title: pageTitle,
        cssFile1: index-styles,
        script1: index-script
    });    
});
```

**/routes/index.js**

```
exports.index = function(req, res, index-styles, index-script) {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Home',
        cssFile1: index-styles,
        scriptFile1: index-script
    });
};
```

I managed to set this up with the title of the page, but I'm new to Express and I'm not entirely sure what's wrong when I do `<%= cssFile1 %>. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate CSS files for different pages, I would use a setup where each page-specific CSS file would be stored in a page-specific file (or directory):

```
public/css/index.css  // the 'default' file
public/css/home.css   // for the 'home' page
public/css/login.css  // for the 'login' page
...
```

Then, in the `render` call I would pass the name of the CSS file that should be loaded:

```
res.render('index', { cssFile : 'login' });
```

And in your EJS template, use that *or* the default if the `cssFile` property wasn't passed:

```
<% var cssFile = cssFile || 'index'; %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/<%= cssFile %>.css">
```

Any other CSS files that are specific to each page can be `@import`'ed from the page-specific CSS files.

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but I'm a little new to express. Do you know how I can say in my `app.js` to require or load my css folder?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean :)

Comment: How does the first bit of code i.e. the css files get loaded by Express when I do a render?

Comment: Oh right, that's usually handled by `express.static`. See [here](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content) for a bit more information.

Comment: Ok so I set up my stuff and it works, but if I delete the `|| 'index'` part, then `cssFile` == `undefined`. Why?

Comment: @IlanBiala you are passing the `cssFile` argument to `res.render()`? If not, it *should* be undefined if you leave out the `|| 'index'` part (that's short for `if (! cssFile) { cssFile = 'index'; }`)

Comment: @IlanBiala variable names in JS cannot contain hyphens (`-`)

Answer (score 0):

you can just use javascript to output your conditional css

```
if(document.title.indexOf("YOUR TITLE STRING HERE") >= 0){ 
INSERT YOUR CSS LINK
}
```

Comment: Even though this would work, I don't want to depend on the final title string because that is different and may change, compared to the title of the page, which will most likely not change.

Comment: it's just an example mate, you can change that to your variables